# Adding column to a gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms

I currently have a gridview that is set up and working properly but I ran into a little bit of an issue.  My grid's datasource is being set from a DB table and one of the columns in the table is the numeric ID of another table.  Rather than displaying this numeric ID in the grid, I need to display a description column off of the other table.  Can I add an additional column to my current gridview just for display purposes?

Comment: Can you? Yes. Should you? No. How are you populating the data in the data source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can accomplish this by using a template on your ID field rather than creating a new field.  [This link has some examples.](http://www.asp.net/data-access/tutorials/using-templatefields-in-the-gridview-control-cs)  This way you can custom format your existing column.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a data-set and bind this dataset to the gridview. 
Using the data-set, you can add rows, columns. The below example is a good one to add rows/columns to the grid-view. You can also follow the same example with a little bit of tweaks. 
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/dynamic_Columns_in_Grid.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Set AutoGenerateColumns to false, and define the columns that you want to display:

```
                <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CellPadding="4" CellSpacing="0" AutoGenerateColumns="false" Width="100%">
                    <RowStyle BackColor="#ffffff" />                            
                    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#f5f5dc" />
                    <HeaderStyle BackColor="Beige" ForeColor="#333333" Font-Bold="true" Height="25px" />                        
                    <Columns>
                        </asp:TemplateField>                                                            
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Address">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <%# Eval("Address") %>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                   </Columns>
             </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: The data source would still have to have a description to pull from for the new column, or a bunch of logic in code to try to figure out a description for who knows how many numbers. Better to just add it to the data source if possible.

Answer (score 0):

The change should be made in 3 locations:

1. The `datasource` should have the `desc` column brought back with it.  Do the join in the database and bring it all back at once so the front end will not need to make an insane amount of calls.
2. On display, you can set the `id` column to invisible.  This can be done on the code behind or on the aspx.
3. On edit, if it is a value that is based off of a look-up table, you will need to create a drop down list.  You can query for more info if edit is needed, if not, the top two points should cover your needs.